# How to have an array of objects based routing in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React. But I am familiar with Vue. In Vue with the Vue Router, we can have an array of objects based routing like,

```
const routes = [
{
   name : "Login",
   path : "/login",
   component : ()=> import('views/Login.vue') //for lazy loading
   meta : {
    auth : false // this means no authentication needed for this particular route
    }
},
{
   name : "Dashboard",
   path : "/dashboard",
   component : ()=> import('views/Dashboard.vue') //for lazy loading
   meta : {
    auth : true // this means authentication needed for this particular route if the user is not authenticated, they will be redirected to login page
    },
}]
```

What I tried so far is as below :

**Login.jsx**

```
const Login = () => {
  const onClick = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("token", "admin");
  };
  return <button onClick={onClick}>Login</button>;
};

export default Login;
```

**Dashboard.jsx**

```
const Dashboard = () => {
  return <h1>Dashboard</h1>;
};

export default Dashboard;
```

App.js

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { Redirect, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";
import Login from "./Login";

const App = () => {
  const routes = [
    {
      path: "/login",
      component: Login,
      auth: false,
    },
    {
      path: "/dashboard",
      component: Dashboard,
      auth: true,
    },
    {
      path: "/example",
      component: Example,
      auth: true,
    },
  ];
  return (
    <>
      <Switch>
        {routes.map((route, index) => {
          return (
            <Fragment key={index}>
              {route.auth ? (
                <>
                  <Route
                    exact
                    path={`${route.path}`}
                    component={route.component}
                  />
                 </>
              ) : (
                <>
                  <Route
                    exact
                    path={`${route.path}`}
                    component={route.component}
                  />
                </>
              )}
            </Fragment>
          );
        })}
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

But in the above approach, I am always getting redirected to "/login". Is there anyways to fix this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your `map()` call renders all of the elements in the array, and the last element renders a `<Redirect .../>` component pointing to `/login`. You end up rendering a redirect for every route. Also, don't use `index` as key.

Comment: @pilchard can you suggest the changes ? If the user is logged in I need to redirect to dashboard if not i need to redirect to login. How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this [React-View-Router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-view-router) package help you. Instead of react-router-dom, try this package, and you can follow vue-router like syntax

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not use Router in React like this.

video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Law7wfdg_ls

Doc: https://reactrouter.com/

what is happening in your code is:

you are running a map and the first item is "login" that's why when the first item of your array came to the map it redirect to "login" and the moment this happens your application is switched to a different route and the next two iterations for your map will not execute.

this is how I do this in any application and it's really good for high scale applications:
(This is the sudo code)

```js
// code for your router.js JSX

<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    // you can define your other routes here
    <AppRouter
      path={"/profile"}
      exact
      layout={AuthLayout}
      component={Profile}
    />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>;

// below functions ideally should written in a utility file

const AuthLayout = withRouter((props) => {
  const [View, setView] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    setView(
      // you can write your own check here
      localStorage.getItem("access_token") ? (
        props.children
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/" />
      )
    );
  }, [props]);

  return (
    <div className="App-Main-Div">
      <div className="main-section">
        <Base header footer pathName={pathName}>
          {View}
        </Base>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
});

const AppRouter = withRouter(
  ({ component: Component, layout: Layout, ...rest }) => (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => (
        <>
          <Layout>
            <Component {...props}></Component>
          </Layout>
        </>
      )}
    ></Route>
  )
);


// after doing all this you just need to put your router file in your App.js return statement
// which might look like this

const App =()=>{
    // this router is your custom router you need to import it also
    return <Router/>;
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for answering. What I want is an array of protected routes and public routes. If user is logged in they should be redirected to Dashboard else they should be redirected to login page

Comment: I have never done routing that way in reactjs. every framework has its own way of doing things. I am not saying that it's not possible, but I would never do that on my application.

Comment: Oh but why? I mean generally almost all VueJS applications follow this approach yet they all are working as expected. I do understand but I think it would be a minimized and efficient approach

Comment: But you are using ReactJs, it's not VueJS so it has a different way of doing things. 
I understand that having the data in an array and separating them in terms of protected and public routes is really convenient. but at the same time, in ReactJs we use JSX and when you create your router it's a react component. I already explained that why your code is miss behaving. at last, I would say that every framework has pros and cons, and react is no exception.